# Was this scene in Dollhouse retconned out of existence?

Tags: dollhouse

In the episode "Epitaph 1", a group of survivors ("actuals") find the dollhouse.  They learned how the events of the apocalypse happened by using the imprinting chair to view the memories left by the main team (Echo, Adelle, Topher, etc.).

In one of these memories, Mr. Ambrose is using the body of Anthony/Victor, and explaining to Adelle and Topher that they are now in the business of offering immortality to whoever can pay enough.  Rossum still seems to be operational at this time, and Adelle and Topher still seem to be working for them.

However at the end of season 2, we see Anthony/Victor go from hive mind soldier, to the attic, to defending the L.A. dollhouse, to Tucson helping to blow up Rossum.  There doesn't seem to be any time where he would be imprinted with Mr. Ambrose for that scene while Adelle and Topher were still working for them.

Is there an in universe explanation, or did they just decide this scene to have not happened later?